# Cython Hello World: Module Not Found; helloworld.pyd not created

Tags: python, module, cython, setup.py

I've looked at the other Cython "Hello World" questions and their errors are very different than mine. I apologize if this is a duplicate question -- I'd love to see what I'm duplicating because I've looked all over. I'm following the instructions here: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html

Here's my `helloworld.pyx`:

```
print("Hello World")
```

My `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("helloworld.pyx")
)
```

I went to the command line and ran `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`, then ran `import helloworld' in the Spyder console (and then in a Jupyter notebook, just in case).

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-39f3e3c18221>", line 1, in <module>
    import helloworld

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helloworld'
```

The tutorial said the command should have created a file called `helloworld.pyd`, so I searched my entire computer for that file and found nothing.

I'm using Python 3.7.3 on 64-bit Windows. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to be sure, do you have your setup.py file in the same folder as the helloworld.pyx? And are you in this directory when you try to import the module interactively? Besides that, what is the feedback of `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`? If no .pyd file was produced, there was probably something not successful.

Comment: The `setup.py` and `helloworld.pyx` are in the same folder. I changed the working directory to that same one before I tried to import (based on your comment), but got the same result. There is no feedback from the command `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` -- no error and no "success" message.

Comment: Ok, this is a bit strange but it is a hint that not everything is installed/set up correctly. Maybe you find more advice [here](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/InstallingOnWindows). Installing via Anaconda (if you are not already doing this) may be the easiest for a start. Try in a fresh virtual environment. Also make sure you have a compiler (e.g. MinGW) installed. You can check if Cython works for  example in a Jupyter Notebook, too (%load_ext cython, %%cython).

Comment: Based on your comment I went to the Anaconda command prompt and installed Cython (stupid me -- I thought it was already installed). The %%cython magic worked in a Jupyter notebook yesterday, but I'm trying to run this from Spyder. I changed all the directories (in the command line and the Spyder REPL) to match the directory where the helloworld.pyx and setup.py are saved, and I have Visual Studio 2019 installed so I assume that would work as a compiler. (Good call on all these points -- I hadn't thought of them. Clearly I'm in over my depth.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Extension` in your setup.py file, such that you have:

```py
# setup.py

from setuptools import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

extensions = [Extension('helloworld', ["helloworld.pyx"])]

setup(ext_modules = cythonize(extensions))
```

Then run `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` again and the error should be gone, i.e. the module should be found.

Comment: Thanks!! I have spent 3 hours for a solution and this worked. But I cannot understand what's the difference of doing this way